# How to fix LocalDb in windows7

Tags: c#, localdb

I created an application using Localdb that works perfectly on Windows 8 and 10(Just with Sqllocaldb installation), but it does not work on Windows 7. I installed all versions of Sqllocaldb on Windows 7, but it also has the following error:

> a network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a >connection to sql server. the server was not found or was not accessible. >verify that the instance name is correct and that sql server is configured to >allow remote connections. (provider: sql network interfaces, error: 26 - >Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

connection string:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\V12.0;AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath + @"\db\IndexProject.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
```

please help

Comment: Did you escape correctly the _(LocalDB)\v12.0_ part like you do for the _@"\db\IndexProject...._?

Comment: Yes, it works on other windows